# This OutputStream Code Does't Save the String into the Txt File

Tags: java, android, outputstream

This outputStream Code bellow can Work.. but plzz tell me where  can i  make a Text File.. i have put it On My deskTop..

```
Button input = (Button) findViewById(R.id.input);    
input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String str = "MY NAME IS OZEER AHMAD, I BELONGS FROM KASHMIR. DOING BCS FROM PESHAWAR UNIVERSITY";
                FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput(str, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
                w.write(str);
                w.flush();
                w.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Data Inserted IN OUTPUT FILE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "ERROR FOUND IN OUTPUT FILE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Assalam o Aliekum.. please remove `w.flush();` after `w.write()`

Comment: its not working Brother #MubashirHanif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong parameters to openFileOutput, the first parameter is the file name not the string which you want to write into file, use this code:

```
String fileName="SOMEFILENAME.txt";
String str="this is the string you will see inside the file";
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream=openFileOutput(fileName,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                outputStreamWriter.write(str);
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `w.flush();` after `w.write(str)`.

since the writing is done not immediately from the buffer but when buffer has sufficient amount of data or is closed. calling `flush()` on the stream deletes all the data in it whether its written or not.